# Can you form a group with assembly instructions under the MIPS-32 architecture?

Tags: group-theory

Would it be possible to form such a group using the `ADD` instruction and the `NOT` instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  The integers modulo $2^{32}$ form a group.  The group operation is addition modulo $2^{32}$, which can be implemented by the ADD instruction.  You don't need the NOT instruction.

There are other groups you could form, such as the integers modulo 2, and many more.  I recommend you read the definition of a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) and play around with some examples.